# Alter auto render for controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to alter the autorender views in cake 2.3.5, either but overriding something or method name conventions?

I want to render views in subfolders of the main Controller directory, here is an example:

```
class AdministrationController extends AppController {

    public function products(){ 
        $this->render('/Administration/products/index');
    }
}
```

I would rather store the views in organized subfolders like this:

```
- Administration
  - products
    - index.ctp
    - edit.ctp
```

My question is: Is there a way to rework this so that I don't have to use `$this->render()` in every action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

Either call render with a path relative to the corresponding view folder:

```
$this->render('products/index')
```

Or call with an "absolute" path which is understood to be relative to the view folder:

```
$this->render('/Administration/products/index');
```

Both of these calls will render the view file `app/View/Administration/products/index`. If you want to structure your view files like that - you either call `render` in each action or manipulate the [viewPath](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L123) variable to point where it needs to be (either in the class, or in the beforeFilter).

### An Administration controller is not normal

In the question there is `Administration` , `products` and `index` - all normal things, but it's *not* normal to have an Administration controller. With that kind of controller structure the Administration controller will become huge.

The normal way to do that would be to use [admin routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) and define an admin index:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {

    function admin_index() {
         //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm rebuilding a custom admin panel from scratch, and am only looking for an answer to the question.

Comment: How odd. You mean, like the one provided (`If you want to structure your view file..`)?

Comment: Yeah, the reason is there are alot of admin pages and would rather organize them into separate folders under the administration, or is cake sort of picky about the folder structure.  It would be best if I could organize everything that has to do with the administration system, under that directory, and not have to jump around in products, etc.

Comment: Cake isn't picky, it simply has conventions. You can organize your files however you want so long as, though configuration or explicitly, you tell your app where to find it's view files. It's not apparent from the question if there is any kind of logic that would permit deriving the file name.

Comment: Cake is opinionated however, so outside of the standard conventions, I take it, you're on your own... thanks

Comment: Not really. Cake is about convention over configuration - not "our way or the high way". You can probably use [App::build](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#adding-paths-for-app-to-find-packages-in) to configure where cake looks for things however you want - you aren't providing any information to give you a specific advice though.